# How to directly verify the following function satisfying the ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Background: In Minkowski space, I have a field satisfying the following wave function:
$$(-\partial_t^2+\nabla^2-m^2)\phi(\vec x,t)=0$$
Then I use Fourier transformation to get an plane wave solution:
$$\phi(\vec x,t)=e^{i (x_1k_1+x_2k_2-u t)}$$ where $u=\sqrt{m^2+k_1^2+k_2^2}$
Then I make the following coordinate transformation to Rindler space:
$$\rho e^\tau =x_3+t,\quad \rho e^{-\tau}=x_3-t$$
Then in the new coordinate $(x_1,x_2,\rho, \tau)$, the wave function take the following form:
$$((\rho\partial_\rho)^2-\partial_\tau^2+\rho^2(\partial_{x_1}^2+\partial_{x_2}^2-m^2) )\phi(x_1,x_2,\rho,\tau)=0$$

And the wave function in the new coordinate is:

$$\phi=e^{i(k_1x_1+k_2 x_2-u \frac{\rho e^\tau-\rho e^{-\tau}}{2})}$$

Once again I make another Fourier transformation on $\tau$

$$f(w;k_1,k_2,u,\rho)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\tau e^{i(k_1x_1+k_2 x_2-u \frac{\rho e^\tau-\rho e^{-\tau}}{2})} e^{i w \tau} =e^{i(k_1x_1+k_2 x_2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s^{iw}}{s}e^{-iu \rho /2(s-1/s)}ds$$

Thus we can get an solution to the ODE:
$$((\rho\partial_\rho)^2+w^2-\rho^2u^2)\phi(\rho)=0$$
which is:
$$\phi(\rho)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s^{iw}}{s}e^{-iu \rho /2(s-1/s)}ds$$

My question is that how to verified it's a solution directly?

Comment: Is that $e^{-iu\rho/(2(s-1/s))}$ or $e^{(-iu\rho/2)(s-1/s)}$?

Comment: $e^{\frac{-iu \rho}{2}(s-\frac{1}{s})}$

Comment: Actually, just ODE there, $w$ and $u$ are just parameters. I played it around  but can not see some structure there.